# Arduino Lipo Battery Voltage Reading

Tags: arduino, power-supply, voltage-divider, lipo, drone

I would like to read the voltage of a Lipo 4s battery with an arduino.
The arduino can only support 5V in input, so I made a shematic of my voltage divide.

Can you tell me if it is correct ?

[image]

Materials:

- Arduino nano
- Lipo 4s (FCONEGY 1800mAh 14.8V 80C)
- PDB (Matek 6 ESC Output)

Answer (score 0):

First it's important you have in mind arduino adc is optimized for analog signals with an output impedance of 10k or less.

With those resistors you plan to use the impedance is about 136k (560//180) so its better you choose lower value resistors.

Comment: Or put a 100nF capacitor across R2.